# Create custom driver using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to create my custom driver using Codeigniter

Files structure:

```
/libraries
    /Test_driver
         /drivers
              Test_driver_first_driver.php
         Test_driver.php
```

Driver super class:

```
class Test_driver extends CI_Driver_Library 
{ 
     function __construct() 
     { 
          $this->valid_drivers = array('test_driver_first_driver');  
     } 
}
```

Driver Subclass :

```
class Test_driver_first_driver extends CI_Driver 
{
     function index() 
     { 
           echo "Hello world!"; 
     } 
}
```

Testing code in welcome.php Controller :

```
$this->load->driver('test_driver');
$this->test_driver->test_driver_first_driver->index();
```

but the output was : "Invalid driver requested Test_driver.test_driver_first_driver".
Does any one have any idea, Unfortunately Codeigniter user guide does not contains steps for creating custom driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its best practice or i should say my thinking that **i always avoid underscores in parent class for the driver**
so for me the file structure is some what like this

```
/libraries
    /Testdriver
        /drivers
           Testdriver_first_driver.php
    Testdriver.php
```

**Testdriver.php**

```
<?php
  class Testdriver extends CI_Driver_Library 
 { 
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->valid_drivers = array('testdriver_first_driver');
     }
 }
```

**Testdriver_first_driver.php**

```
<?php
    class Testdriver_first_driver extends CI_Driver 
    {
         public function index() 
         { 
             echo "Hello world!"; 
         } 
    }
```

**In controller**

```
$this->load->driver('testdriver');
$this->testdriver->first_driver->index();
```

Note : **even if you don't use ucfirst() it will still work**

i.e. Folder `testdriver`

Files -

`testdriver.php` (`class testdriver extends CI_Driver_Library`)

**and**

`testdriver_first_driver.php` (`class testdriver_first_driver extends CI_Driver`)

hope it is helpful. :)

Comment: how to auto load testdriver?

Comment: @motaz according to me as of now drivers cannot be auto loaded directly. please correct me if I'm wrong. but i use parent class constructor to load it so its similar to auto load itself for e.g. in constructor of `My_controller extends CI_controller` we load required drivers and in `A_controller extends My_controller` we can use it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Karan's answer but I removed the parent's name in valid_drivers' value:

```
<?php
  class Testdriver extends CI_Driver_Library{


    function __construct(){
      $this->valid_drivers = array('first_driver');
    }
  }
?>
```

This worked for me, you might want to give it a try. Credits to Karan.

Answer (score 0):

I have just grappled with this in CodeIgniter v2.2.0 so thought I'd chip in. The scant documentation on custom drivers isn't too helpful as the example does not show the complete setup. The existing core CodeIgniter drivers are not organised in a consistent way either, with the driver parent class files being in different directory locations to where the docs say they should be etc. so you have little to go by but to consult the core Driver Library code.

In your given situation, the driver is seen as invalid is because you are effectively adding on the parent class name twice when calling it. This:

```
$this->test_driver->test_driver_first_driver->index();
```

Should be changed to:

```
$this->test_driver->first_driver->index();
```

Looking at the core code that the driver parent class extends:

```
class CI_Driver_Library {

    protected $valid_drivers = array();
    protected $lib_name;

    // The first time a child is used it won't exist, so we instantiate it
    // subsequents calls will go straight to the proper child.
    function __get($child) {
        if (!isset($this->lib_name)) {
            $this->lib_name = get_class($this);
        }

        // The class will be prefixed with the parent lib
        $child_class = $this->lib_name . '_' . $child;
```

Note the last line there. Basically, CI was trying to load a driver class named "Test_driver_test_driver_first_driver", which of course didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

For codeignaiter 3 problem in core system libraries driver.php 
testdriver_first_driver.php

```
class Testdriver_first_driver extends CI_Driver {
public function index() 
         { 
             echo "Hello world!"; 
         } 
}
```

testdriver.php

```
class Testdriver extends CI_Driver_Library{
function __construct(){
        $this->valid_drivers = array('first_driver');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter SPL Autoloader

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Autoloader function
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Add to the bottom of your ./application/config/config.php file.
|
| @author Brendan Rehman
| @param $class_name
| @return void
*/
function __autoloader($class_name)
{
    // class directories
    $directories = array(
        APPPATH . 'core/',
        // add more autoloading folders here� and you�re done.
    );

    // for each directory
    foreach ($directories as $directory)
    {
        // see if the file exsists
        if (file_exists($directory.$class_name.'.php'))
        {
            require_once($directory.$class_name.'.php');
            // only require the class once, so quit after to save effort (if 
               you got more, then name them something else

            return;
        }
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('__autoloader');
```