# Codeigniter driver call parent method in child construct

Tags: php, codeigniter, driver

I have a problem implementing a Driver in Codeigniter.

I need to access a method of the parent class as a global variable in a child class.

This is my code

Parent Class

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Prueba extends CI_Driver_Library  {

    protected $notifica_grupo;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->valid_drivers = array('uno', 'dos');
        $this->notifica_grupo     = "foo";
    }

    public function notifica_grupo() {
        return $this->notifica_grupo;
    }
}
```

Child Class

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Prueba_uno extends CI_Driver {

    private $ci;
    protected $notifica;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $this->notifica = $this->_parent->notifica_grupo();
    }

    public function test1(){
        echo $this->notifica;
    }

}
```

I get the following error when calling $this->prueba->uno->test1();

```
    Type: Error

    Message: Call to a member function notifica_grupo() on null

    Filename: /xxx/application/libraries/Prueba/drivers/Prueba_uno.php

    Line Number: 10

    Backtrace:

    File: /xxx/application/controllers/Test.php
    Line: 33
    Function: __get
```

So, my question is... Is there a way to access parent method from child's construct?

**UPDATE**:
I tried different ideas, none worked. These have been the scenarios:

1. Trying to get the variable directly instead to get from the parent's method: `$this->notifica = $this->_parent->notifica_grupo;`. Result:

```
Message: Trying to get property 'notifica_grupo' of non-object
```

2. Changing "extends CI_Driver" to "extends Prueba" in Child class. Result:

```
Invalid driver requested: Prueba_uno__parent
```

3. Changing "extends CI_Driver" to "extends Prueba" in Child class, and removing the "_parent" in the variable value, in child constructor to: `$this->notifica = $this->notifica_grupo();`
   returns this error:

```
Message: Call to undefined method Prueba_uno::decorate()
```

4. Adding `parent::__construct();` in child constructor, then trying to get the value from parent method or directly the variable. Returns:

```
Type: Error
Message: Cannot call constructor
```

Comment: You should write `class Prueba_uno extends Prueba ` instead of `class Prueba_uno extends CI_Driver `

Comment: Hi @L.Faros I tried with it, but it still doesn't work. I have updated my question to show the different errors in different cases. BTW im using CodeIgniter not pure PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You are not extending the parent class. Your child class must use the parent class name to extend which is Prueba. And you are extending CI_Driver

You need to use parent class for this you can do this 
$this->notifica = Prueba ::notifica_grupo();

Hope this helpful

Comment: From what I understand, the child classes in a CodeIgniter Driver must extend CI_Driver and not the parent class. Do you have information about whether it is valid or good practice not to extend CI_Driver and instead extend the parent class name? I have implemented the changes you indicated, extend the parent class, and call the method through $this->notifica = Prueba::notifica_grupo(); The result is the following error: ```Message: Call to undefined method Prueba_uno::decorate()```

Comment: I think this can help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530989/create-custom-driver-using-codeigniter/23533390